# How to select a single Edit text box from a gridview with base adapter?

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I am using a `GridView` 6*6 and it consists of `EditText` for a total of 36 `EditText`.

I am passing a 2D array from the base class and the values are filled in the correct position. The boxes which are not filled are made invisible.

Now I need to find the first visible `EditText` box and make focus automatically, and after certain event I need to change the focus to next visible `EditText`?

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

         ViewHolder viewHolder;

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        String comonchar = String.valueOf(hint_lilst.get(0));

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.crossword_play_screen_items, null);
            viewHolder.tv1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CW_oneone);
            viewHolder.gridView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.Cw_gridviewplay);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.tv1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);


        Log.d("macantiosh","child at "+viewGroup.getChildAt(21));

        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
          //  arrayList.get(position);
            viewHolder.tv1.setText(arrayList.get(position));

        }


//        if (Objects.equals(arrayList.get(position), "0")) {
//            viewHolder.tv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//            viewHolder.tv1.setClickable(false);
//        }
//


        if (Objects.equals(arrayList.get(position), comonchar)) {
            viewHolder.tv1.setText(arrayList.get(position));
            viewHolder.tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.puzzlesucess);
            viewHolder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }else if (Objects.equals(arrayList.get(position), "0")) {
            viewHolder.tv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            viewHolder.tv1.setClickable(false);
        } else {
//            for(int m = 0; m< filled_pos_llist.size();m++){
             //   if(Objects.equals(arrayList.get(position),focus_pos_wrds.get(filled_pos_llist.get(0)))){
                    viewHolder.tv1.setText("");
                   // viewHolder.tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.puzzlesucess);
                    //viewHolder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                  //  viewHolder.tv1.requestFocus();
                    Log.d("popi", "list words" + arrayList.get(position));

               // }
//            }
        }

                if (viewHolder.tv1.getVisibility() ==View.VISIBLE){
            filled_pos_llist.add(position);
        }
        Log.d("adgads","words in list pos "+viewGroup.getChildCount());


        //GridView mGridView =viewGroup;

//        final int size = viewGroup.getChildCount();
//        Log.d("timber","child count in grid view "+size);
//        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
//            ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
//            int childSize = gridChild.getChildCount();
//            for(int k = 0; k < childSize; k++) {
//                if( gridChild.getChildAt(k) instanceof EditText ) {
//                    gridChild.getChildAt(k).setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                    Log.d("khaggj","got pos list visible positionss ");
//                }
//            }
//        }














//        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : focus_pos_wrds.entrySet()) {
//
//            viewHolder.tv1.requestFocus(1);
//            viewHolder.tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.puzzlesucess);
//            viewHolder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
//
//            Log.d("khaggj","got pos list  "+entry.getKey());
//            break;
//
//
//        }


        final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
        viewHolder.tv1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {

                if (hasFocus) {

                    Log.d("djhgfj", "on focus change lisiner    " + position);
                    finalViewHolder.id = position;
                    current = (EditText) view;
                    current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.focusedtxt);
                    click_pos = position;
                    Log.d("djhgfj", "on focus change lisiner    " + finalViewHolder.id);

                }

            }
        });


        keyboard.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.d("clickk", "clicked item " + keyboard_words.get(i) + "    n  " );

                EditText current_edittext = getCurrentEditText();

                if (current_edittext != null) {

                    if (current_edittext.getText().length() == 0) {

                        current_edittext.setText(current.getText().toString() + keyboard_words.get(i));

                    }


                    if (current_edittext.getText().toString().equals(arrayList.get(click_pos))) {
                        Log.d("txtchange", " filled  answer crrt ");
                        current_edittext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.puzzlesucess);
                        current_edittext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

//                        if(Objects.equals(arrayList.get(position),focus_pos_wrds.get(filled_pos_llist.get(0)))){
//                            viewHolder.tv1.setText("");
//                            viewHolder.tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.puzzlesucess);
//                            viewHolder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
//                            viewHolder.tv1.requestFocus();
//                            Log.d("popi", "list words" + arrayList.get(position));
//                            current = viewHolder.tv1;
//                            current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.focusedtxt);
//                            click_pos = posiztion;
//                        }

                    } else {

                        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.shake);
                        current_edittext.startAnimation(shake);
                        current_edittext.setText("");


                    }
                }

                Log.d("pendrive", "adapter clicked  class   " + keyboard_words.get(i) + "   current  " + click_pos);


            }
        });


//        for (int i = 0; i < filled_pos_llist.size(); i++) {
//
//            ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
//
//            if (gridChild.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText && ((EditText) gridChild.getChildAt(i)).getText().length()>0){
//
//                    Log.d("thanaser", "visible individual  positions  ");
//
//            }
//
//        }

        final EditText current_edittext = getCurrentEditText();
        if (current_edittext!=null){
            current_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    if (current_edittext.getText().toString().length()>0){

                        Log.d("hdjhiu","text changed ");
                    }
                }
            });
        }




        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: use position of gridview item!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by going throw all `GridLayout` child `Views`:

```
public void setFocusOnEditText() {
    GridLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof EditText && view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            view.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using your custom `BaseAdapter` and if I'm not mistaken you could use:

```
if (convertView instanceof GridLayout) {
   View editText = ((GridLayout) convertView).getChildAt(position);
   if (editText instanceof EditText && editText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
      editText.requestFocus();
   }
}
```

Comment: is this possible to add in adapter class?

Comment: What kind of adapter we talking about? If you would show the part of the adapter code, I could try to help you

Comment: using base adapter with custom keybioard

Comment: So if your base adapter is class of custom adapter which extends `BaseAdapter` so you can do it by using `int position` parameter instead of `i` in this method. And it will be much simpler than this method

Comment: no nothing works as expected when i run this code   GridLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof EditText && view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            view.requestFocus();
        }
    } the loop runs for 36 times but the visible edittext is not focused.

Comment: @Sri if you are using this in Adapter you should use the second method. And if focused should be just first of all visible Views, so I offer you to use `break;` in `if()` after focus request.

Comment: @Sri You should show the code of your adapter or where you are using these methods otherwise the question will be closed